# How to create radiobuttons programatically on a datagridview

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, radio-button

I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2010. I have a datagridview on a winform. I would like 1 column to contain radio buttons only. Each row would have 3 radio buttons. I'm not sure I understand what is needed for that. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: radiobuttons not supported in datagridview. So you can use a checkboxes and then write code for checkboxes working as radiobuttons... Then put some code in question: what did you tried to do, if still no succes

Answer (score 0):

create a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` and connect to the `CellContentClick` event. then use this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)// checkbox column
     {
        object curr =
           dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;

        if (curr == null || (bool)(curr) == false)
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
           {
              if (i != e.RowIndex)
              {
                 dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, i].Value = false;
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```